# Accessing PHP Scripts Without .php Extension

Tags: php, file

How do you configure Apache and/or PHP to be able to access PHP scripts without the .php extension? I have seen PHP scripts executed without the .php extension. I don't mean executing 'script' as a PHP file, I mean executing 'domain.com/script' as a PHP file where 'script.php' exists as a file, but you are able to access it without using the extension. Does anybody know how to configure this?

I AM USING A CPANEL HOSTING!

WHERE TO WRITE THE mod_rewrite? I HAVE A .htaccess file with code `# Do not remove this line or mod_rewrite rules and search engine friendly URLs will stop working RewriteBase /`

Comment: I think you are asking that You dont want to show extension in url.right?
you need to write htaccess rules for this.

Comment: i had written my code plz explain

Comment: -1 for the excessive capslock usage

Comment: What is wrong with having the .php extension in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

Several basic ways:

- Use MultiViews. Automatically converts /foo => /foo.php (among other things)
- Use mod_rewrite to remove PHP extensions
- Use mod_rewrite to direct all traffic to a single dispatcher script, which inspects the URL and performs the proper action by including files / calling class methods, etc.

Comment: WHERE TO WRITE THE mod_rewrite? I HAVE A .htaccess file with code `# Do not remove this line or mod_rewrite rules and search engine friendly URLs will stop working
RewriteBase /`

Comment: The simple solution is to add `Options +MultiViews`. It's kind of an abuse of what it's meant to do, but it works. For anything else, see Amber's link.

Comment: @harikrishnan0007, you may want to post your .htaccess on a code sharing site and link to it on your question.

Answer (score 0):

Generally that's done in Apache via `mod_rewrite`.

Here's a guide: http://wettone.com/code/clean-urls

Answer (score 0):

Such a rewriting doesn't make too much sense.

If you want (SEO-firiendly|human-readable) URLs, you have to use complete set of rewrite rules, not just removing extension.

Otherwise there would be no point in such a configuration change